# Upload Multiple files in Django 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am new to pyhthon\Django and would like to get my Django 3 app to have the ability to upload multiple files but I am struggling to get this functionality, below is my sample code which uploads a single file, I beleive I need to enable multiple files in the forms.py and then override the post method to deal with multiple files.
As I bonus I would also like to use a field name from the form in the file path when it is saved.

(Pyhton 3.8/Django 3)
thanks

Model.py

```
    class Predocs(models.Model):
        doc_files = models.FileField(blank=True)
```

Form.py

```
    from .models import Predocs
    class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Predocs
            fields = ['doc_files']
```

View.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    
    # Create your views here.
    from .forms import PostForm
    from PredocsForm.models import Predocs
    
    
    def create(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                # save form
                form.save()
                data = "test data"
                return render(request, 'preform/created.html', {
                    'data': data
                })
        else:
            form = PostForm()
    
        return render(request,
                      'preform/create.html',
                      {
                          'form': form
                      })
    
    
    def created(request):
    
        return render(request, 'preform/created.html')
```

Comment: take a look at this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html